# XMLTABLE has atomic value issue

Tags: xml, ibm-midrange

I am very new to XMLTABLE and this may be a very silly question.

For the Below Query:

```
   Select T1.*
    From XmlTable ('$d/Order/OrderHeader'                                      
         Passing '
         <Order>
            <OrderHeader>
                <OrderId>a</OrderId>

            </OrderHeader>
         </Order>'  As "d"  
   Columns                                                                          
   OrderId Char(7) Path    'OrderId'           


   ) as T1;
```

I am getting an error of

> SQL State: 10507 Vendor Code: -16011 Message: [SQ16011] The result of
>   an intermediate step expression in an XPath expression contains an
>   atomic value

I am not exactly sure Why is this. It would be great if anyone could Guide me on what is wrong

Comment: For a description of what that error really means: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014603888

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the XML explicitly instead of passing a string value:

```xml
SELECT T1.*
FROM XMLTABLE (
  '$d/Order/OrderHeader'
  PASSING XMLPARSE (DOCUMENT '
    <Order>
      <OrderHeader>
        <OrderId>a</OrderId>
      </OrderHeader>
    </Order>') AS "d"  
  COLUMNS
  OrderId CHAR(7) PATH 'OrderId'
) AS T1;
```